# npm packages requires Angular 2 and 4

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, package.json

In pacakge.json, there are 2 npm libraries that requires 2 different versions of Angular -
`ng2-translate` and `ngx-infinite-scroll`. For `ng2-translate`, it only supports Angular 2, but for `ngx-infinite-scroll`, the lowest version supports Angular 4.

> peer @angular/common@">= 4.0.0" from ngx-infinite-scroll@0.4.0

Is it okay keep Angular 2 and have both `ng2-translate` and `ngx-infinite-scroll`? What's the best practice?

Comment: You might be better off just upgrading everything to the latest version. This really is too old to touch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running `npm install --force` to skip npm dependencies compatibility check.

This is not the best solution but you can use your packages while waiting for the maintainers to update their version of angular.